# In TSQL, how to order by "most occurring" values?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using AdventureWorks, for example, I want to get a list of all employees and their managers, with the managers having the most subordinates at the top.  Easy enough to get the number of reports each manager has by using a GROUP BY, but I want the actual list of their subordinates, on separate rows.

```
SELECT
  Subordinate.LoginID, Subordinate.Title, Manager.LoginID, Manager.Title
FROM
  HumanResources.Employee Subordinate
  JOIN HumanResources.Employee Manager
    ON Subordinate.ManagerID = Manager.EmployeeID
ORDER BY 
  ??
```

Comment: Do some managers manage managers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are on at least SQL Server 2005 you can use

```
ORDER BY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Manager.LoginID)  DESC
```

Although I suppose

```
ORDER BY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Manager.LoginID) DESC,  Manager.LoginID
```

might be better to avoid potentially mingling result rows for managers with tied numbers of subordinates.

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for.